# Spring-Boot jndi email lookup support

Tags: spring-boot

Does spring-boot allow you to define a jndi lookup for mail-server resource?
I could not find any documentation indicating that it does support it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support in Spring Boot for looking up a `javax.mail.Session` from JNDI. If it's something you'd like to see, please [open an enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new).